# Accessing Firestore from Firebase Realtime Database Security Rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm actively using both of Firebase Realtime Database and Firestore. There is a case in which I need to check a document on Firestore to allow user to write on Firebase Realtime Database.

Basically, I need to access user's document in the `users` collection on Firestore to allow user to create a post under the `posts` node on Firebase Realtime Database.

Is something like this possible, by any chance?

```
"rules": {
  "posts": {
    ".write": "get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(auth.uid)).data.isVerified == true",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to cross products between in security rules.

The best you can do is mirror data between the two products where needed for rules.